# No input signal after installing Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, system-installation, dell

I have a Dell Precision 5820 workstation with a wiped hard drive, and I was trying to install Ubuntu 20.04 on it (I believe it used to have Ubuntu 18.04 before the wipe). Everything worked fine up until I was told to click restart now to finish the installation. I removed my usb drive and pressed enter as instructed, after that there was no input signal anymore. I'm new to installing Linux systems, and I really haven't got a clue after looking up similar issues, so any advice is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by no input signal anymore? Nothing on monitor screen?

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi Yeah my monitor shows no input signal detected and just turns off, it was working during the installation steps, so I know the monitor and the cables are working

Comment: @guiverc Sorry for being unclear, I was trying to install Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS Desktop

Comment: Does the live cd/usb still boot correctly? Or, did you install Ubuntu another way?

Comment: @user3169 I installed Ubuntu with a bootable usb drive, I'm not sure how to test that without a second desktop

Comment: Did the live system (try it, not install Ubuntu) work ok? It should run from the usb drive without installing anything.